# JPA Unknown SqlResultSetMapping when several persistence unit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to map the result of a stored procedure to an entity list and I am guided by the following post https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping .
Now I am having the next error:

> org.hibernate.procedure.UnknownSqlResultSetMappingException: The given
> SqlResultSetMapping name [Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [Foo]] is
> unknown

I suspect that the problem could be that I am working with several databases in my project.

How could I specify the context or persistence unit in which the resultMapping is?

Comment: How are you getting that exception - it must come from a persistence unit. As the error implies, you need the result set defined within THAT persistence unit. Entitymanagers/persistence units are self contained, they cannot and do not reference artifacts (like result set mappings) from other persistence unit definitions.

Comment: How do i set the result set defined within THAT persistence unit ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are missing as you posted a tutorial that is fairly detailed and shows how to define the ResultSetMapping and native queries that use them through annotations which are picked up by the persistence unit (so on classes within those persistence units). How have you defined yours, how are you executing your query, and what persistence unit are you using? I don't think anyone can help without more details on what you are doing to connect multiple databases; specifics on your setup. You might try getting it to work in a single DB/persistence unit before expanding though.